ｗhat is the difference between のだった and のだ

トットちゃんは、少しは残念だったけど、（校長先生が困ってるんだもの、いいや）と、すぐ決めたのだった。

this is the original sentence from the book 窓際のトットちゃん，but I can't wrap my head around the part のだった．
As far as I know, のだ is used for explanation like

Ａ：どうして遅れたんですか。
Ｂ：ごめんなさい｡バスが来なかったんです。

but how のだった works? how does it differ from

トットちゃんは、少しは残念だったけど、（校長先生が困ってるんだもの、いいや）と、すぐ決めたのだ。


"のだ is used for explanation" - well, that's the nuance, but the grammar is just nominalizing の + copula だ. And だった is just the past form of だ. Of course we can explain present conditions and also separately explain past conditions.

Duplicates:

The concept of past perfect in Japanese ～たのでした　～たのです
Why is のだった used
here?

Related: 過去形＋のだ versus 現在形＋のだった
Kurosio's A Handbook of Japanese Grammar Patterns has the following entry on this (p503):

のだった〈strong feeling〉

田辺はそれが贈賄であると知りながら、金を渡したのだった。／ Even though he knew it was a bribe, Tanabe handed over the money.

この小さな事故が後の大惨事のきっかけとなるのだったが、その時はことの重大さにだれも気づいていなかった。／ This slight mishap would trigger the disaster that came later, but at the time nobody realized its importance.


This use of のだった is comparable to Usage 1 of のだ ["explanation"]. However, のだった is used when describing a past event with some kind of emotion. Often seen in written Japanese, such as novels and essays.

My teacher (native Japanese) has likewise explained this as "basically the same as のだ but used in narratives and storytelling for emphasis".
And just to cite every source I can think of, have Meikyou's definition and example sentence for this as well, why don't you:
《「…─・だった」の形で》過去のことを詠嘆的に表す。「ようやく平和が訪れた─・だった」
